# File type is returning null in chrome browser

Tags: php

I have used file uploader(used PHP) in my application.

In FireFox, and Internet Explorer8 working when I try below statement.

```
print $_FILES['upladed']['type'];
```

But in chrome I am getting null value(not printing anything).

If I use `var_dump($_FILES['upladed']['type']);` then I am getting result as

```
string '' (length=0)
```

Please suggest some pointers.

Thanks

-Pravin

Comment: PHP does not print anything if it encounters a NULL value. What is the exact output? Any errors?

Comment: It's not printing anything..and also I am not getting any error.

Comment: What are you trying to print actually?

Comment: I wanted to know file type...e.g. text/html

Comment: what's the file name you trying to upload? does it have an extension, if the type comes up null you should treat it as `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `var_dump($_FILES['upladed']['type'])` to figure out if it's really NULL or not.

Second of all, I don't know what's wrong with Chrome, but you should not rely on this value in your PHP application. Always validate the data over the wire than checking what MIME type the browser really *claims to be*. In Windows, MIME types can be changed in registry, for instance.

Comment: PHP should get rid of this value some point of future I think.

Comment: If I used var_dump($_FILES['upladed']['type']) then I am getting result string '' (length=0)

Comment: @BoltClock: cause s**t like this happens. Chrome refuses to report the MIME type, some mis-configured systems might report the wrong types, some hackers might fool your application to take her/his file by reporting a *safe* MIME file type.

Comment: @timdream, Whether we rely on it or not depends on the application.  It may be desirable to know what the browser is reporting.  It isn't up to the language to decide what we do with that information is secure or not.  Also, Chrome reports the MIME type for me just fine... perhaps I have a different version?

Comment: @Brad, I agreed with you. However it's better to design a language with security in mind right? There are just too much PHP programmers out there do things like read MIME types from here, forget `htmlsepcialchars()` when `print` ... ruin the reputation of all.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome (up to at least 8.0.552.215) has issues with content types of files. For me, it was if the file did not have an extension.

See: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6800

Note: I'm using struts 2.0.14 with the FileUploadInterceptor (uses ServletFileUpload and JakataMultipartRequest)